# Tooltip on hover using JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have this map in html and I want to show "Lina Garcia's picture with some text over the circle (id="circulo-show") when I hover the mouse.

How do I select where I want my photo to appear using jquery?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Gobierno Corporativo</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/default.js"></script>
    <style>
        #lina-garcia {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#miembro-ext-1").mouseover(function() {
                $("#lina-garcia").css("display", "block");

            });

            $("#miembro-ext-1").mouseout(function() {
                $("#lina-garcia").css("display", "none");
            });
        });
    </script>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <img id="comite-inversiones" src="https://www.afiuniversal.com.do/Style%20Library/Images/gobierno-corporativo-chart.png" usemap="#mapa-comite">

        <map name="mapa-comite" class="mapa">
            <area target="" alt="" title="" href="" id="miembro-ext-1" class="seccion" coords="150,113,315,14" shape="rect">
            <area target="" alt="" title="" href="" id="miembro-ext-2" class="seccion" coords="342,13,499,118" shape="rect">
            <area target="" alt="" title="" href="" id="especialistas-1" class="seccion" coords="112,141,199,295" shape="rect">
            <area target="" alt="" title="" href="" id="especialistas-2" class="seccion" coords="453,139,542,300" shape="rect">
            <area target="" alt="" title="" href="" id="adm-fondo" class="seccion" coords="146,327,315,428" shape="rect">
            <area target="" alt="" title="" href="" id="especialistas-3" class="seccion" coords="342,329,494,428" shape="rect">
            <area target="" alt="" title="" href="" id="circulo-show" coords="326,222,114" shape="circle">
        </map>
    </div>
    <div id="lina-garcia">
        <a>Lina Garcia<img src="https://www.afiuniversal.com.do/sobre-afi-universal/Imagenes/consejo-administrativo/img-gobierno-lina-garcia.jpg"/></a>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you please re-phrase your question? It's not clear

Comment: Sorry my english is kinda bad, Here's what I want, Whenever somebody hovers over "miembro-ext-1", I want the photo to be displayed in "circulo-show", so far, using jquery I managed to make it happen, however, I have zero knowledge in positioning an object. Hence why I need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you want, but anyway I think what you are looking for is jquery's .hover function which you can implement like this:

```
$("#circulo-show").hover(function() {
  $("#lina-garcia").css("display", "block");
  }, function() {
  $("#lina-garcia").css("display", "none");
});
```

REF: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_hover.asp

If you want to know how to position your image as a tooltip which you want to make visible using jquery when somebody hovers, then that is solely determined by your css which you can modify to suit your needs.

If that is the case, then you can use [this code](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_tooltip), change the span element to the image that you want, and make further customizations however you want.